# Python Pandas Error printing the column headings

Tags: python, pandas, tokenize

I'm trying to import an excel sheet with data into python using pandas but I get a pandas parser error where the expected fields are 10, but saw 11.

when I specify the columns it prints all the data plus their column headings but double the column heading as a row of data.

```
import pandas as pd
columns=['bookID','title','authors','average_rating','isbn','isbn13','language_code','# num_pages','ratings_count','text_reviews_count']

df = pd.read_csv (r'path of the csv file', name=columns)
print(df)
```

## shows the column heading

```
bookID | title | authors | average_rating | isbn |isbn13 | language_code | # num_pages | ratings_count | text_reviews_count
```

## and then again adds the column heading as the first row of data

```
0  | bookID | title | authors | average_rating | isbn |isbn13 | language_code | # num_pages | ratings_count | text_reviews_count
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can simply use `header='infer'` as you already have the column headers in the CSV file which you are reading from.

```
df = pd.read_csv (r'path of the csv file',header='infer')
```

[pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)